# How to exclude escape characters from ROOT when using FOR JSON from SQL server

Tags: json, sql-server, for-json

I am trying to create JSON output from SQL Server using FOR JSON. My JSON record is good however I have a number of elements I need in the ROOT section but this is resulting in escape characters which is causing issues.

My select statement is as follows;

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(a.ACCNT_CODE) AS ACCOUNT_REF,
       'PK1' AS SUN_DB,
       RTRIM(a.TREFERENCE) AS REFERENCE,
       RTRIM(x.GNRL_DESCR_25) AS ISR_NUMBER,
       '' AS CHECK_DIGIT,
       '' AS PAID_DATE,
       '' AS PAID_FLAG
FROM PK1_A_SALFLDG a
     JOIN PK1_A_SALFLDG_LAD x ON a.ACCNT_CODE = x.ACCNT_CODE
                             AND a.JRNAL_NO = x.JRNAL_NO
                             AND a.JRNAL_LINE = x.JRNAL_LINE
WHERE LEN(RTRIM(x.GNRL_DESCR_25)) > 15
FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES, ROOT('FORMATCODE":"CHMCT","TYPE":"PA_B4B_AUX_CHMCT_ISRReference","DATA');
```

But the ROOT is being output as

```json
{"FORMATCODE\\":\"CHMCT\\",\\"TYPE\\":\\"PA_B4B_AUX_CHMCT_ISRReference\\",\\"DATA":[
```

How can I exclude the backslashes from the ROOT element?

Comment: That format is valid, you are stating you want the **name** of the root to be *"FORMATCODE":"CHMCT","TYPE":"PA_B4B_AUX_CHMCT_ISRReference"* *not* the contents. Sample data, and expected results will help us help you here.

Comment: Couple of side notes: Aliases like `a` is for `Customer` and `b` is for `Account`, or `t1` is for `Purchase` and `t2` is for `Transaction` aren't helpful for you or others that want to read your code. Use meaningful and *consistent* aliases for your objects. I suggest a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: Also whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation, instead of all left aligned text, and line breaks, really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to abuse `ROOT` to include JSON data. Have you tried nested JSON queries yet?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying to embed extra JSON data into `ROOT`. Instead of trying to do that try instead to use a nested JSON query, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
  'CHMCT' as [FORMATCODE],
  'PA_B4B_AUX_CHMCT_ISRReference' as [TYPE],
  (
    SELECT
      RTRIM(a.ACCNT_CODE) AS ACCOUNT_REF,
      'PK1' AS SUN_DB,
      RTRIM(a.TREFERENCE) AS REFERENCE,
      RTRIM(x.GNRL_DESCR_25) AS ISR_NUMBER,
      '' AS CHECK_DIGIT,
      '' AS PAID_DATE,
      '' AS PAID_FLAG
    FROM PK1_A_SALFLDG a
    JOIN PK1_A_SALFLDG_LAD x
      ON a.ACCNT_CODE = x.ACCNT_CODE
      AND a.JRNAL_NO = x.JRNAL_NO
      AND a.JRNAL_LINE = x.JRNAL_LINE
    WHERE LEN(RTRIM(x.GNRL_DESCR_25)) > 15
    FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
  ) DATA
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER;
```

Which will yield output similar to...

```json
{
    "FORMATCODE": "CHMCT",
    "TYPE": "PA_B4B_AUX_CHMCT_ISRReference",
    "DATA": [
        {
            "ACCOUNT_REF": "...",
            "SUN_DB": "PK1",
            "REFERENCE": "...",
            "ISR_NUMBER": "...",
            "CHECK_DIGIT": "",
            "PAID_DATE": "",
            "PAID_FLAG": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply.  All sorted.